# Wordpress Ajax for search results - Query returns only 1 result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, while-loop

Here is my problem, I've been trying to create a Ajax call to get my search results but my problem is that I can only retrieve 1 result in json. There is some problem with my loop which I can't understand so far.

Here is my HTML, where the results should be loaded from the ajax action.

```
<div id="project-grid">
</div>
```

I call the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
     search_things();
});

function search_things(){
    var searchformdata = new FormData();
    searchformdata.append('action','search_results');
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: searchformdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend:function(data){
            //alert(searchformdata);
            //console.log(searchformdata);
            $('#project-grid').html('Loading...');
        },
        success:function(data) {
            $('#project-grid').append(data.projectsresults);
            //console.log(data.projectsresults);
            //alert(data.projects);
        },
        error: function(data){
            //console.log(data);
        }
    });
    //alert("a");
}
```

Now, of course I've created this little fuction in my `functions.php`

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_search_results', 'search_results');
add_action('wp_ajax_search_results', 'search_results');
function search_results(){
    $returnprojects = return_query_projects();
    $response = array('projectsresults' => $returnprojects);
    wp_send_json( $response );
}
```

Which calls the `return_query_projects()` (where my loop is stored) looking like:

```
function return_query_projects(){
        global $wp_query, $query_string;
        $query_vars = $wp_query->query_vars;
        $post_per_page = 10;
        $closed = array(
                'key' => 'closed',
                'value' => "0",
                'compare' => '='
        );
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'project',
            'order' => 'DESC', 
            'orderby' => 'date', 
            'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
            'paged' => 1,
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                $closed,
            ),
            'post_status' => array('publish'),
        );
        $html = array();
        query_posts($args);
        if ( have_posts() ): 
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                $html = get_post_main_function();
            endwhile;
        else:
            $html = '<div style="color:#fff; margin-top:15px">' . __('No projects posted here yet.',"Dev") . '</div>';
        endif;
        return $html;
    }
```

As you can see, I've created a kind of box in another box with the hope to take it flexible. So my last function `get_post_main_function();` is something like this:

```
function get_post_main_function()
{ 
  global $post, $current_user;
  wp_get_current_user();
  $pid = get_the_id();
  //Some other variables

  $html = array();
  $html = '<div class="card project" id="post-' . $pid . '">';

  //other code for structure

  $html = '</div>';
  return $html;
}
```

This code is returning **1 only post**, but I know there are many others. What's going wrong? I suppose there is something in the post loop but I don't know how to fix it. Can you give me some directions? Thanks.

Comment: Use this `$html += get_post_main_function();` instead of `$html = get_post_main_function();` as to add recursive `html`

Comment: Hey @RonyLoud thanks for your help! I've tried but I get Internal Server Error with that from my admin-ajax.php... Is there another way?

Comment: As `$html` is a `array` you need to use `$html.push(get_post_main_function())` to store the returning element in `array` node

Comment: @RonyLoud oh damn, what a dumb I am... Thanks to your suggestion I've just used `$html[]` instead of `$html`, it started to work! Sorry to have bothered... If you want let's write an answer and I'll thumb up for you! Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$html.push()` in place of adding `$html` as string

Try this `$html.push(get_post_main_function())` in place of `$html=get_post_main_function()`